# How to solve loading rdlc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, rdlc

When I call the .aspx file to show the report, the rdlc report is loading,
and not showing the report; the loading start when I set parameters on .aspx file?
How do I solve this?

```
var data = db.Database.SqlQuery<MPWAttReportVM>(@"exec getting data").ToList();

        TestRV.SizeToReportContent = true;
        TestRV.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("WebForm3.rdlc");
        TestRV.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

        ReportParameter[] paras = new ReportParameter[3];
        paras[0] = new ReportParameter("FromDate", "2019-01-01");
        paras[1] = new ReportParameter("ToDate", "2019-04-20");
        paras[2] = new ReportParameter("Days", Days);
        TestRV.LocalReport.SetParameters(paras);
        ReportDataSource ds = new ReportDataSource("MinistryAttReportDT", data);
        TestRV.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(ds);
        TestRV.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Resulting image:

[[image]]

Comment: when exporting data is it ok ?

Comment: i cant export data from which report,

Comment: if you mean getting data from database, database return data and write on Var data

Answer (score 0):

I think its styling issue espically in google chrome browser.

try this solution

Set this attribute in your `ReportViewer` tag inside aspx page :

- `ZoomMode="PageWidth"`
- `SizeToReportContent="True"`

example :

```
<your_reference_name:ReportViewer ID="rptView" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100%" ZoomMode="PageWidth" SizeToReportContent="True"></your_reference_name:ReportViewer>
```